# Событие при горизонтальном скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

Дано:

1. страница с горизонтальным скроллом (jInvertScroll.js),
2. при появлении определённых блоков навешивать класс на других блоках.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать при горизонтальном скролле?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll top на left  Y на X

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось проще отталкиваться от высоты страницы, которая прописывается в скрипте инициализации jInvertScroll.js

То есть, получилось несколько условий:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 3000 && $(window).scrollTop() < 4500) {
    // наш экшен
}
```